# jsrsasign - how to extract an x.509 certificate's fingerprint?

Tags: javascript, security, cryptography, digital-signature, x509

Is it possible to use jsrsasign to extract the fingerprint of an x.509 certficate, similar to what can be achieved using this openssl command:

`openssl x509 -sha1 -in cert.pem -noout -fingerprint` - Ref: [openssl x.509 doc](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html)

I'm reading my X509 like so:

`var c = new X509();
c.readCertPEM(cert);
\\ how to get the fingerprint?`

Ref: [jsrsasign x.509 apidoc](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/X509.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to extract the string from between the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" header and "-----END CERTIFICATE----- " footer, base64 decode it and compute SHA1 hash of decoded data.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for using jsrsasign. You can write like this:

> hex = KEYUTIL.getHexFromPEM(certPEMstring);
>
> fingerprint = KJUR.crypto.Util.hashHex(hex, 'sha256');

You can also find a fingerprint example here:
http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/tool_certview.html

Answer (score 1):

In the version of jsrsasign 10.7.0, You can achieve this by

```
import { KJUR, pemtohex } from "jsrsasign";


const hex = pemtohex("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...... -----END CERTIFICATE----- ");
const fingerprint = KJUR.crypto.Util.hashHex(hex, "sha1")
```