# How to get the same fingerprint that AWS uses from x.509 with node-forge?

Tags: javascript, node.js, x509certificate

How to get the certificate ID / fingerprint of an x.509 certificate using [node-forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge)?

**Update**

I need this for AWS IoT. I've been investigating and ended up that AWS probably uses some fingerprint algorithm to extract the certificate ID. It is not baked into the cert, probably the public key is used as a base for the fingerprint.

**Update 2**

Running this command returns the correct fingerprint: `openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha256 -inform pem -in cert.crt`

How to achieve this with [node-forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge)?

I've put together the following one but it does not return the same fp.:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const forge = require('node-forge')
const { pki } = forge
const { promisify } = require('es6-promisify')
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile)

async function main() {
  const certPem = await readFile('./cert.crt', 'utf-8')
  const cert = pki.certificateFromPem(certPem)
  const fingerprint = pki.getPublicKeyFingerprint(cert.publicKey, {
    md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
    encoding: 'hex',
  })
}

main()
```

Comment: Which problem you have?

Comment: I'm creating x509 certificates for devices and want to assign these to users.

Comment: Actually I need the same certificate ID that AWS uses.

Comment: I think that's an sha256 fingerprint... But for some reason I can't get the same one AWS extracts when I upload the cert.

Comment: You may want to include this information in your question so that it can be answered: The algorithm used by AWS to determine the "ID" and the code you are using

Comment: You are calculating the fingerprint on the publicKey, but you need to do it on the entire certificate. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970290/how-to-get-x509certificate-thumbprint-in-javascript/42971511#42971511 . I think you can use the same code just changing the digest method to sha256

Comment: It makes sense that the fingerprint should be calculated on the entire certificate, but it is still not correct with the SHA256 version of your code either.

Comment: the code basically makes the hash sha1 of the content of the certificate. It should work in the same way as the one you indicate in your answer.

Comment: I needed to explicitly remove the head and the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811640/jsrsasign-how-to-extract-an-x-509-certificates-fingerprint) is:

> You just need to extract the string from between the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" header and "-----END CERTIFICATE----- " footer, base64 decode it and compute SHA1 hash of decoded data.

In this case SHA256.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the solution of haxpanel with some code in your requested NodeJS code:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

function getCertificateFingerprint(certString) {
    const baseString = certString.match(/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*-----END CERTIFICATE-----/i);
    const rawCert = Buffer.from(baseString[1], "base64");
    const sha256sum = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(rawCert).digest("hex");
    return sha256sum.toUpperCase().replace(/(.{2})(?!$)/g, "$1:");
    // eg 83:6E:3E:99:58:44:AE:61:72:55:AD:C6:24:BE:5C:2D:46:21:BA:BE:87:E4:3A:38:C8:E8:09:AC:22:48:46:20
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here you are. The result will same as `openssl x509 -in a.pem -fingerprint -sha256 -noout`

```
  import forge from 'node-forge'
  fingerprint() {
    const der = forge.asn1.toDer(forge.pki.certificateToAsn1(cert)).getBytes()
    const m = forge.md.sha256.create().start().update(der)
    return  m.digest()
        .toHex()
        .match(/.{2}/g)
        .join(':')
        .toUpperCase()
  }
```